# Bookshelf JS Relation - Getting Count

Tags: node.js, postgresql, relational-database, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to get users count belongs to specific company.

Here is my model;

```
var Company = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'companies',
    users: function () {
        return this.hasMany(User.Model, "company_id");
    },
    users_count : function(){
        return new User.Model().query(function(qb){
            qb.where("company_id",9);
            qb.count();
        }).fetch();
    },
    organization: function () {
        return this.belongsTo(Organization.Model, "organization_id");
    }
});
```

- method "users" works very well, no problem.
- method "users_count" query works well, but cant get value to "company" model.

in routes, i'm using bookshelf models like this;

```
new Company.Model({id:req.params.id})
            .fetch({withRelated:['users']})
            .then(function(model){
                res.send(model.toJSON())
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                res.send(error);
            });
```

How should i use users_count method, i'm kinda confused (probably because of promises)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Collection#count()**

If you upgrade to 0.8.2 you can use the new [`Collection#count` method](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-count).

```
Company.forge({id: req.params.id}).users().count().then(userCount =>
  res.send('company has ' + userCount + ' users!');
);
```

**Problem with your example**

The problem with your `users_count` method is that it tries to make Bookshelf turn the result of your query into Models.

```
users_count : function(){
  return new User.Model().query(function(qb){
      qb.where("company_id",9);
      qb.count();
  }).fetch(); // Fetch wanted an array of `user` records.
},
```

This should work in this instance.

```
users_count : function(){
  return new User.Model().query()
    .where("company_id",9)
    .count()
},
```

See relevant discussion [here](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/126).

**EDIT: How to get this in your attributes.**

Maybe try something like this:

```
knex = bookshelf.knex;

var Company = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'companies',
    initialize: function() {
      this.on('fetching', function(model, attributes, options) {
        var userCountWrapped = knex.raw(this.getUsersCountQuery()).wrap('(', ') as user_count');
        options.query.select('*', userCountWrapped);
      }
    }
    users: function () {
        return this.hasMany(User.Model, "company_id");
    },
    getUsersCountQuery: function() {
      return User.Model.query()
        .where("company_id",9)
        .count();
    }
    organization: function () {
        return this.belongsTo(Organization.Model, "organization_id");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you are pointing 0.8.2. Your example work, thanks, but here is another question. I want to get users_count as a company models property. Is it possible? Btw, count returns result as an array, is it normal? I just need an integer.

Comment: Sorry, 0.8.2 is correct. It should [return an integer (or a string in the case of node-pg)](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/blob/584f22fbe9b272168393c1a07e8e50e5eab8ffc0/test/integration/collection.js#L71-L120). If you're getting a different response you've found a bug. Please raise an [issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues) containing the relevant details.

Comment: "company models property" - do you mean you wish for the count to appear as an attribute?

Comment: is this solution supposed to work for belongsToMany relations too?

Comment: @mezod Yes, it is. Please if there are any problems first try latest release then report an issue on Bookshelf's GitHub page.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [bookshelf-eloquent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-eloquent) extension. The withCount() function is probably what you are looking for. Your code would look something like this:

```
let company = await Company.where('id', req.params.id)
    .withCount('users').first();
```

Comment: Nice catch brother, it's an amazing package for the people who are familiar with `Laravel's` `Eloquent` and `Query-Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.collection().query(function (qb) {
  qb.join('courses', 'users.id', 'courses.user_id');
  qb.groupBy('users.id');
  qb.select("users.*");
  qb.count('* as course_count');

  qb.orderBy("course_count", "desc");
})
```